# What resources exist for WxRuby: documentation, tutorials, samples?

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, wxruby

I found the [RubyForge](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org) documentation, which is a little tricky to navigate.

There's a [basic tutorial](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/11/getting-started-with-wxruby-gui-toolkit.html) on the [Ruby On Windows](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com) blog. But I've already moved on from that.

What other WxRuby resources have you found useful?

Or, if not WxRuby specifically, what Wx resources have you found useful from a Ruby perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the tumbleweeds, er, tumbled around this question, I discovered that there are extensive (about 60) samples in the, er, `samples` directory for the wxruby gem. There's a big all-in-one demo, called `bigdemo.rb` that shows off all kinds of useful and exciting things.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the installer I think, not sure, you should see a folder inside wx's main folder, its called `doc`, otherwise, just google '*wxruby*' and the name of the class or object you want to know about,

For example:

> file:///C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wxruby-ruby19-2.0.1-x86-mingw32/doc/auimanager.html

As you can see, the URL is my hard drive. I'm not sure where to direct you, but this is the most useful resource I have found yet, I'm not sure about the more complex controls of widgets, but I'm sure `wx` isn't the best GUI out there.

If want, I wouldnt mind emailing the folder to you, there are several hundred html documents of very useful information on it